# chain conditional css with normal css attribute

Tags: css, angularjs

I'm using ng-style in angularJs to style an element like the following 
the first part is conditional style that depends on the value of isEdit if it's true pass empty object if not set color to grey , the second style should be applied regarless of the first part.

the code I used didn't seem to work

```
ng-style="isEdit? {}: {'color': 'gray'}, leftStyle"
```

is there a way to chain the 2 styles and make them work at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can achieve that by merging the styles in a method and then calling it in template

```html
<h1 ng-style="isEdit ? {} : getStyles()">
    {{ heading }}
</h1>
```

```js
var style1 = {
  color: "white",
  "background-color": "coral",
  "font-size": "60px",
  padding: "50px",
};

function _getStyles() {
  return Object.assign({}, style1, {
    border: "3px solid black",
  });
}
```

[Working Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-nobel-lczek?file=/src/index.js:229-438)